# Polygon "Fixing" Algorithm

Tags: java

I bring you a maybe complex question which i would love your help with. Allow me to go straight to the point:

I desire an algorithm or logic in which i draw a shape using my mouse (for example a square) and it becomes a perfect square, with all the 4 sides in straight lines and perfectly regular. A human-drawn square is hardly perfect, but i wish that after it goes through the "filter" of this algorithm ,it becomes such.

A fine example of what i wish is in the game Trine, where the Wizard works by a similar principle: You draw a shape in the screen and it becomes the closest shape, that is, if you draw something similar to a square it becomes a perfect square box, but if you draw a triangle it becomes a perfect triangular box. Its like it detects what kind of shape it is and then draws a better version of it.

I want this for a game, just so you know what is the goal of all this.

Please help me figure out either the algorithm or logic behind this, or at least tell me what is the name of this kind of action (:

P.S. i added a simple image so it becomes even more clear what i intend =)

[image]

Comment: Keywords: pattern matching, feature extraction. (And if you want to go straight to the point, just do it..)

Comment: Have the user click at each vertex. Count the number of mouse clicks and make vertices at the first click and floor(.5 + middle'th) click. Then draw a regular polygon.

Comment: clicking at each vertex would nullify its objective, which is allowing the user to draw the shape he desires. If i told him to click in 4 vertex i would be imposing the user to draw a square, while he might want to draw a triangle. And i was really hoping for a system similar, if not equal, to Trine's wizard =p

Comment: @user2295607 What other shapes you want to recognize? Triangles (what kind of?), rectangles, trapezoids, deltoid, ... Circles, ovals, arches?

Comment: Mainly squares, triangles (equilateral), lines (for the game bridge platforms) and if possible circles

Comment: Is this for Android?  If so, you could use Android's [Gesture API](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html).

Comment: no its for windows =p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to implement this task, I would store the recognizable patterns, and would try to make a match for them.

Take the minX, maxX, minY, maxY values form the user-drawn points, that will help you to scale the pattern. Choose the scaling so that the aspect ratio for the pattern would be the average of the X and Y aspect ratios.

The patterns can consist of certain number of straight lines. The pattern matches if

- There are no points outside of the threshold
- There is at least one user-drawn point close to each key points in the pattern

If you have the pattern matched, you will have the key points for your pattern (calculating the center of your pattern, and the size/aspect ratio). Then you can replace the user-drawn points with your image - that may be totally different from the pattern used to match (imagine a circle).

Comment: This might be indeed the simplest logic to implement ^^

Comment: Not that difficult. You can also try to match rotated or flipped versions of your pattern, if you implement the transformation of you key points.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One way that you could do it is to create a neural net that recognizes these shapes. I would generate variations of circles, squares, lines, and triangles with random perturbations to replicate "hand-drawn" versions. Then you would want to represent this as a two-dimensional array (where locations that have been drawn on would be 1's and locations that haven't been drawn on, would contain 0's). You can then convert this two-dimensional array into an input vector of `n x n` elements. The output of the neural net would be a vector with four elements, each one representing either a line, circle, square, or triangle. You would then train this neural net using your randomly-perturbed images until you end up with a neural net that recognizes the input with an error that is under some error-threshold. This is actually quite similar to recognizing handwritten digits.

Other ways include:

- [Shape contexts](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/shape/sc_digits.html).
- [k-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)
- [Support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)

Comment: I did not quite understand what a neural net is nor what you mean by "training" it in therms of programming, but i understood your logic, not a bad idea (: it seems hard to implement though... I will check your links now ^^

Comment: @user2295607 Yes, it's a little involved but it should give you the best output. :) The bonus is that you would learn something neat!

Comment: by the way, is it still viable to use neural nets if the drawn square has no fixed size? that is, from what ive understood, to "train" the neural net, you need to give it examples, but the examples might vary in size since the drawn square can be from different sizes, and the result square also, which in my mind nullifies the use of neural net a bit :/ correct me please

Comment: @user2295607 Yes, if you scale the image to a specific size, it should still work out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have just an arbitrary shape, you also have the shape's path.  So try counting corners.  Decide on a angle threshold that will represent a corner.  For each point, sample the next consecutive x number of points.  Measure the angle between the first half and second half.  If the angle surpasses your threshold, consider it a corner.  (Obviously select the point that give you the best angle with the least amount of error, not just the first one that surpasses the threshold.) Mark the location of the corners and draw your shape to match.

Ellipses & lines: if no angles are detected, sample a few segments.  Measure the orientation.  If they are very similar, then line.  If very different, then ellipse.  If ellipse, find the bounding box and draw inside.